# Подскажите пожалуйста почему это не работает?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

if (body === ".page-1") {
    alert('123');
}
```

Comment: Это работает, и в коде ошибок нет. Просто условие никогда не выполнится, из-за *человеческой* ошибки.

Comment: У документа есть свойство body. Нет необходимости его искать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (document.body.classList.contains("page-1") {
    alert('123');
}
```

Comment: `body` - список же.

Comment: @Suvitruf, замените body на document.body

Comment: Сколько у него тел?

Comment: @Igor в `getElementsByTagName` может быть что угодно. Просто в текущей постановке там `body`, поэтому больше 1 быть не может. Я бы, всё же, отвечал на более общий вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

А чего вы хотите добиться? `getElementsByTagName` вам возвращает колекцию DOM объектов.

Если вы хотите найти элементы с тегом `body`, чтоб у них был класс `page-1`, то вот так надо:

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

for(var i = 0; i < body.length; ++i){
  if (body[i].classList.contains("page-1")) {
      alert('123');
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="page-1">
  <div>
  test text
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы сравниваете HTML Elemnts с текстом.

Если вам нужно проверить наличие body с классом ".page-1", то можно сделать так:

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body.page-1')

if (body !== null) {
  // do what you want
  console.log('click!')
}
```

```html
<body class='page-1'>
```